# Get next element with same class in jquery on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to create the following.

I have a button and on click of that button i need to add some active class to a div, but i have 4 divs with same class. What am trying to create is like a Choose Bet system like when you click first time on button you choose the first bet, when second time the second, i have 4 bets.

My html structure is the below

```
<div class="game_paytable_bluebet_column game_paytable_column"></div>
<div class="three_bet_wrappaer">
     <div class="game_paytable_greenbet_column game_paytable_column"></div>
     <div class="game_paytable_orangebet_column game_paytable_column"></div>
     <div class="game_paytable_redbet_column game_paytable_column"></div>
</div>
```

What i did so far with jquery see below

```
jQuery('.choose_bet_button').click(function(){
    if(!jQuery('.game_paytable_column:first').hasClass('active_blue_bet')){
        jQuery('.game_paytable_column:first').addClass('active_blue_bet');
    }else{
        jQuery('.game_paytable_column:first').removeClass('active_blue_bet');
        jQuery('.game_paytable_column').next().addClass('active_blue_bet');
    }
});
```

With this code it is getting 2 elements.

Any idea how to get a solution to this?

Comment: Doesn't `nth-child()`, `eq()` or `nth-of-type()` works?

Comment: but how i can track the click like is it first click or second click and do some action with eq(), nth-child() etc ?

Comment: I would suggest that you store that in a `localStorage` or `sessionStogare` variable

Comment: can you provide the rest of your code

Comment: @student why the hell you will waste storage in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `:eq()` you can achieve your requirement.
And initialize a counter and based on the counter add class in div.
And every four click make the counter 0.

Please check this snippet.

```js
var _click = 0;
$('.choose_bet_button').click(function(){  
  if((_click % $(".game_paytable_column").length)==0){_click=0;}  

  $('.game_paytable_column').removeClass('active_blue_bet'); 
  $('.game_paytable_column:eq('+_click+')').addClass('active_blue_bet');
  
  _click++;
  if($.trim($(".in_sight_area").html())==""){
    $(".in_sight_area").html('<div class="top_bet_column_two top_bet_column game_paytable_column">New One</div>');
  }
});
```

```css
.active_blue_bet{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="in_sight_area"></div>

<div class="game_paytable_bluebet_column game_paytable_column">1</div>
<div class="three_bet_wrappaer">
  <div class="game_paytable_greenbet_column game_paytable_column">2</div>
  <div class="game_paytable_orangebet_column game_paytable_column">3</div>
  <div class="game_paytable_redbet_column game_paytable_column">4</div>
</div>
<br/>
<button class="choose_bet_button">Choose Bet</button>

<div class="game_paytable_redbet_column game_paytable_column">5</div>
```

Comment: Yes i see, works perfectly @Rahul Patel. Will this snippet work if i have one more block connected to this like if the blue is selected some other piece also should get an active state.

Comment: Yes let me make one correction and it will work fine with dynamic divs.

Comment: @AnahitDEV check the snippet now. You can add as many as divs you wants. And revert the down vote if that was the only problem.

Comment: I mean that i have another element on top of this game_paytable_columns in separate div. So i mean can this action be applied to that other div as well?

Comment: Yes.. It will work for all the divs with class name "game_paytable_redbet_column" in the dom.

Comment: @(the person who have down voted) please mention your reason behind down vote.

Comment: Sorry but i added to that other element a class game_paytable_column and code did not work

Comment: Have you checked the updated one? Because I just have added another element in snippet with class "game_paytable_column" and working perfectly.

Comment: Look at the snippet I have added one another div with that class below the button and it is working fine.

Comment: I have on top of the first game_paytable_column and in different container like this <div class="in_sight_area"><div class="top_bet_column_two top_bet_column game_paytable_column"></div></div>

Comment: @AnahitDEV Even it is working fine. Please check updated snippet. I have added it in the snippet.

Comment: I just tried and it is working only for the first bunch of elements in div. Look i have 2 sections which should add active class in the same time

Comment: Ok so when you are adding divs runtime and this snippet is not working for those. Am I right?

Comment: Ok let me check it.

Comment: Check the updated snippet. I have inserted a div on first click of button. As such on first click it is pointed on div with "1" and on second click it is also pointing "1" again instead of next div "2". As 1 was first child before the div added so on first click pointed it and after div added it became second child so on second click also it was pointed. This error will occurred on first cycle only from next cycle it will work fine. So in your case also this error occurs when dynamic divs added for the first cycle of the div addition.

Comment: hey @Rahul Patel thank you very much for your help and useful code. It really save me

Answer (score 2):

Here is an interpretation, please see the comments for a breakdown.

```js
jQuery('.choose_bet_button').click(function(){
  // get all the elements that match your selector
  var $columns = $('.game_paytable_column')
  // get the currently active element
  var $active = $columns.filter('.active_blue_bet')
  // get the index of the active element relative to your columns
  var index = $active.length ? $columns.index($active) : -1
  // increment the index if there is a next element or reset to 0
  var newIndex = ($columns.length > index + 1)
    ? index + 1
    : 0
  
  // remove the active class from all elements
  $columns.removeClass('active_blue_bet')
  // set the new active column
  $columns.eq(newIndex).addClass('active_blue_bet')
});
```

```css
.game_paytable_column {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 4px;
  background: #eee;
}

.active_blue_bet {
  background: #bada55; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="game_paytable_bluebet_column game_paytable_column active_blue_bet"></div>
<div class="three_bet_wrappaer">
     <div class="game_paytable_greenbet_column game_paytable_column"></div>
     <div class="game_paytable_orangebet_column game_paytable_column"></div>
     <div class="game_paytable_redbet_column game_paytable_column"></div>
</div>
<button class="choose_bet_button">choose</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @synthet1c. Your snippet was also helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you have a button... i.e.:

```
<button onclick="next()" >NEXT</button>
```

Seems quite simple:

```
// get all elements with class game_paytable_column
var columns = document.getElementsByClassName("game_paytable_column");

// counter to control the actual index
var counter = 0;

function next() {
    // this selects the actual element and shows content
    alert(columns[counter].innerHTML);

    //and passes to next element
    if (counter == columns.length - 1)
        counter = 0;
    // first if necessary
    else
        counter ++;
}
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://js.do/code/110573)

That's all `:)`